# why i am getting this error in the below code "The method getHeader(String) is undefined for the type HttpRequest"?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying Internationalization and continuously getting this error:

```
The method getHeader(String) is undefined for the type HttpRequest
```

Code:

```
List<Locale> LOCALES = Arrays.asList(new Locale("en"), new Locale("fr"));

public Locale resolveLocale(HttpRequest request) {
    String headerLang = ((HttpRequest) request).getHeader("Accept-Language");
    return headerLang == null || headerLang.isEmpty() ? Locale.getDefault()
            : Locale.lookup(Locale.LanguageRange.parse(headerLang), LOCALES);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide from where you are calling resolveLocale(...) method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HttpServletRequest request`

Change `HttpRequest request` with `HttpServletRequest request`

*Code*

```
public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerLang = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
        return headerLang == null || headerLang.isEmpty() ? Locale.getDefault()
                : Locale.lookup(Locale.LanguageRange.parse(headerLang), LOCALES);
    }
```